# HttpWebRequest.Create and firewalls

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, system.net

I need to check whether a given host is replying to HTTP web requests.
So, all I need to do is HttpWebRequest.Create(someURI) and check the response, right?

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);

TimeSpan timeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOutInSeconds);
webRequest.Timeout = (int)timeOut.TotalMilliseconds;
webRequest.Proxy = proxy;
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false; // get extra information with this turned off, but doesn't affect the problem

response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Well, the problem that's come up is that if someURI is blocked by our firewall (e.g. "gibber.com" is blocked), then I get back a valid HttpWebResponse, it doesn't throw, and the ResponseURI property is set to the blocked URI ("gibber.com") even though it's actually our server responding.

Within the HTTP header there will be a Location key and its value is the IP of the local server. But I don't want to parse text to work out if a request actually bounced. What's the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to parse text?

Comment: Parsing text is easy but doesn't seem very robust. It just spews out n headers and one of them happens to contain the IP of the server. 
If I knew that there will always be a Location header for blocked URLs, and it will always be the address of the server/gateway then great. But I don't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to see if response.ResponseUri corresponds to the given host or your firewall.

Comment: response.ResponseUri is the blocked URL.

Comment: I have to eat an ample helping of humble pie on this one, as I had assumed that the ResponseURI was incorrectly returning the desired host, when in fact it was being blocked. In fact this particular host wasn't being blocked outgoing, but just based on content when incoming, so the ResponseURI here was actually accurate.